# How to Solve this issue while installing laravel

Tags: composer-php, laravel-10

> Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping. The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

i tried as per documentation

this is the error message which i got

Comment: "i tried as per documentation" - what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you have the zip extension installed for PHP. This extension allows PHP to work with zip files. Additionally, you should check if you have the unzip or 7z commands properly set up on your system